# ResultSet in JSON format using JAVA code

Tags: api, youtube

I have a java code that uses YouTube Data API to search for videos based on user entered query. I have the results stored in a Map Data structure of JAVA. I want to get the result in JSON format or store it in JSON file. Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries out there that will do this. Try Jackson or GSON.